# Excel 2013 - Find last non-empty cell in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to find the last non-empty cell in a different sheet than the one I'm using for my calculations.

I've been trying to use the formula `=INDEX(A:A; MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))`, combined with `COUNTIF`. This works fine if used on the same sheet.

Once I use references to the other sheet, I get the `#NAME?` error. Excel seems to get stuck on the first reference to the other sheet.

The sheet I'm working on is called 'Berekeningen', the sheet I'm trying to reference is called 'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'.

Here is my actual code:

```
=COUNTIFS('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F$2:INDEX('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F;MAX(('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F<>"")*(ROW('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F))));Berekeningen!$E$4;'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D$2:INDEX('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D;MAX(('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D<>"")*(ROW('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D))));Berekeningen!$A2)
```

Comment: In formula all references like `'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F` should be `'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:F`

Comment: @Vityata Actually constructions such as F2:INDEX()... are perfectly valid and preferable to volatile alternatives which employ INDIRECT of OFFSET.

Comment: @Leander The construction you are currently employing is extremely resource-heavy, and we could potentially improve it greatly. To do so, it would be useful to know if the entries within the range being passed ('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:F) are text, numeric, or a mixture of both.

Comment: What's more, with COUNTIF(S) it probably isn't worth the effort to pass a reduced range. Referencing entire columns within COUNTIF(S) is not as resource-heavy as with other, array-processing functions such as SUMPRODUCT, AGGREGATE and any formula requiring CSE.

Comment: All values are within these ranges are text. I've already changed the 'Sheet'!F:'Sheet'!F to 'Sheet'!F:F, which solved my problem.

Comment: As you mentioned though, updating all my tables with this new code takes about 2-3min/table. I will just change this to pass the full column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=COUNTIFS('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F$2:INDEX('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:F,MAX(('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:F<>"")*(ROW('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!F:F)))),Berekeningen!$E$4,'B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D$2:INDEX('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:D,MAX(('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:D<>"")*(ROW('B-Closed Cases per teamlid'!D:D)))),Berekeningen!$A2)
```

Comment: This works. I also used this format later but didn't think to actually apply it to this part of the excel sheet.

Thank you!